# Create a new share library using NX

Tags: reactjs, nx-monorepo

I'd like to create a shared component called header under libs/ui/src/lib folder. A couple of years ago I would do the following:

- Use Nx Console and create a new component:
  Nx | Generate | Create a react component
- Use the following information to create the component:
  Name: header
  Project: ui
  Flat: Select the checkbox to ensure we have a flatter folder structure within
- Hit the run button and verify the header.tsx file is created within the libs/ui/src/lib folder.

If a follow the previous instructions, I have to specify the workspace directory and cannot go further after specifying it:
[image]

I have the following output when running `nx --version`

```
Nx Version:
- Local: v14.8.9
- Global: v18.0.4
```

I have been searching how to upgrade the local Nx version with no success.

Do you know how to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: The local version depends on the version defined when executed this command `pnpx create-nx-workspace@14`. So, I should execute this instead `pnpx create-nx-workspace@latest`

Comment: Do you know how can I import an exported class / interface from one library, in the other library, both in the same Nx workspace ? My workspace consists of two application projects and two library projects. I can import members of both libraries in my app projects. But when I try to import between libraries, then I get `Cannot find module "abc" or its corresponding type declarations` error. Do you have any idea ?